# Real life Cramer's Decomposition Theorem example.

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

I just heard of CDT and "tried" to read online documents (Not to mention "understand" it).

**Easy Version Definition:**

> Given independent normally distributed random variables ξ1, ξ2, their sum is normally distributed as well, and vice versa.

But all I can find is the "proves" of the theorem!

Could somebody be so kind and give me a real life example to help me understand it!?

Much appreciated!!!

Comment: You've gathered one close vote for a lack of context (not from me). To avoid further close votes, I would advise stating the theorem in your question, so that people don't have to Google it.

Comment: Updated! Thanks for your warning!